# How can we fetch the Firebase realtime database to List

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Here I am Trying to Display "users" into Recycleview and I need to Get Data Into List

```
databaseReference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val list = dataSnapshot.child("users")

                for (e in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    Log.i("messageData", e.toString())
                }
                Log.i("messageData", userList.toString())
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MessageActivity, "database error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        })
```

[Realtime Database Users Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpIyD.png)

Comment: If someone is helping you by giving an answer to your question with some effort then it's your responsibility to at least accept their answer or if the answer not working then ask again with help of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I got my solutions

```
    private val userList: ArrayList<UserList> = ArrayList()

        databaseReference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {

                    val model = data.getValue(UserList::class.java)
                    if (personalEmail != model?.email)
                        userList.addAll(listOf(model as UserList))

                }
            }
```

#UserList class

```
data class UserList(
    val email: String? = null,
    val full_name: String? = null,
    val phoneNumber: String? = null,
    val profile_image: String? = null
)
```